# Best Approach to load application.yml in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am having Spring Boot application and having application.yml with different properties and loading as below.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="applicationprops")
public class ApplicationPropHolder {

private Map<String,String> mapProperty;
private List<String> myListProperty;

//Getters & Setters 

}
```

My Service or Controller Class in which I get this properties like below.

```
@Service
public ApplicationServiceImpl {

@Autowired
private ApplicationPropHolder applicationPropHolder;

public String getExtServiceInfo(){

Map<String,String> mapProperty = applicationPropHolder.getMapProperty();
String userName = mapProperty.get("user.name");

List<String> listProp = applicationPropHolder.getMyListProperty();

}
}
```

My application.yml

```
spring:
    profile: dev
applicationprops:
  mapProperty:
    user.name: devUser
  myListProperty:
        - DevTestData
---
spring:
    profile: stagging
applicationprops:
  mapProperty:
    user.name: stageUser
  myListProperty:
        - StageTestData
```

My questions are

1. In my Service class i am defining a variable and assigning Propertymap for every method invocation.Is it right appoach?
2. Is there any other better way I can get these maps without assigning local variable.

Comment: how about using an instance variable rather than a local variable?

Comment: The way you load the properties and read them look fine to me. What is your concern in assigning them to local variables everytime you invoke a service method? I am just trying to understand the problem statement better here.

Comment: @St1id3r yes my concern is assigning the same map(static) value to local variable for each method invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope, you are code is fine.

Just use the below

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="applicationprops")
public class ApplicationPropHolder {

private Map<String,String> mapProperty;
private List<String> myListProperty;

public String getUserName(){
    return mapProperty.get("user.name");
}

public String getUserName(final String key){
    return mapProperty.get(key);
}

}

@Service
public ApplicationServiceImpl {

@Autowired
private ApplicationPropHolder applicationPropHolder;

public String getExtServiceInfo(){

final String userName = applicationPropHolder.getUserName();

final List<String> listProp = applicationPropHolder.getMyListProperty();

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are three easy ways you can assign the values to instance variables in your bean class.

1. Use the `@Value` annotation as follows

   ```
   @Value("${applicationprops.mapProperty.user\.name}")
   private String userName;
   ```
2. Use the `@PostConstruct` annotation as follows

   ```
   @PostConstruct
   public void fetchPropertiesAndAssignToInstanceVariables() {
     Map<String, String> mapProperties = applicationPropHolder.getMapProperty();
     this.userName = mapProperties.get( "user.name" );
   }
   ```
3. Use `@Autowired` on a setter as follows

   ```
   @Autowired
   public void setApplicationPropHolder(ApplicationPropHolder propHolder) {
     this.userName = propHolder.getMapProperty().get( "user.name" );
   }
   ```

There may be others, but I'd say these are the most common ways.